# How to Solve msnodesqlv8 npm package Error in Deployment for Render Web Service?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, deployment

I am just a beginner at using nodejs and express JS, recently I used Render web service to deploy my web application, until I came across this particular error on the build logs during the building phase. **error /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/msnodesqlv8: Command failed.** and another error that is  built out of that error is **../src/stdafx.h:37:14: fatal error: sqltypes.h: No such file or directory** and there are lot of more, but the first line of error is the basically the root cause of the error.

The entire build log is shown below

```
=> Downloading cache...
==> Transferred 73MB in 7s. Extraction took 2s.
==> Using Node version 20.11.1 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Running build command 'yarn'...
yarn install v1.22.22
warning package.json: No license field
info No lockfile found.
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
warning No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning mssql-session-store > mssql > tedious > sprintf@0.1.5: The sprintf package is deprecated in favor of sprintf-js.
warning mssql-session-store > mssql > tedious > babel-runtime > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/msnodesqlv8: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
Arguments: 
Directory: /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/msnodesqlv8
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Output:
make: Entering directory '/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/msnodesqlv8/build'
  ACTION binding_gyp_sqlserverv8_target_print_variables src/BeginTranOperation.cpp
cflags_cpp -std=c++17 | arch: x86_64 | link_path: -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L. | msodbc_include_folders  | fileset src/BeginTranOperation.cpp src/BinaryColumn.cpp src/BoundDatum.cpp src/BoundDatumSet.cpp src/CancelOperation.cpp src/CloseOperation.cpp src/CollectOperation.cpp src/Column.cpp src/Connection.cpp src/ConnectionHandles.cpp src/EndTranOperation.cpp src/FreeStatementOperation.cpp src/MutateJS.cpp src/OdbcConnection.cpp src/OdbcConnectionBridge.cpp src/OdbcError.cpp src/OdbcHandle.cpp src/OdbcOperation.cpp src/OdbcStatement.cpp src/OdbcStatementCache.cpp src/OpenOperation.cpp src/Operation.cpp src/OperationManager.cpp src/PollingModeOperation.cpp src/PrepareOperation.cpp src/ProcedureOperation.cpp src/QueryOperation.cpp src/QueryOperationParams.cpp src/QueryPreparedOperation.cpp src/ReadColumnOperation.cpp src/ReadNextResultOperation.cpp src/ResultSet.cpp src/TimestampColumn.cpp src/UnbindOperation.cpp src/Utility.cpp src/addon.cpp src/bcp.cpp src/stdafx.cpp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sqlserverv8/src/BeginTranOperation.o
In file included from ../src/OdbcConnection.h:22,
                 from ../src/BeginTranOperation.cpp:1:
../src/stdafx.h:37:14: fatal error: sqltypes.h: No such file or directory
     #include <sqltypes.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [sqlserverv8.target.mk:174: Release/obj.target/sqlserverv8/src/BeginTranOperation.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/msnodesqlv8/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:209:23)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-1055-aws
gyp ERR! command "/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.11.1/bin/node" "/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/msnodesqlv8
gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
==> Build failed
```

Node Version: v20.11.1

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "msnodesqlv8": "^4.1.2",
    "mssql": "^10.0.2",
    "mssql-session-store": "^1.0.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.9.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

I tried commenting some particular codes in my codebase to do some debugging, I found that

```
const mysql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
```

was the issue, because it is the only part of the code that was having issue with the deployment. To add some details, I checked inside the node modules folder, the msnodesqlv8 package was there. The sqltypes.h was also there, which baffles me. I concluded that I just cannot solve the issue after days of researching.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Comment: my apologies, I am just a new user, I have already converted the images to the corresponding text form